# How to sync only one file type with Unison?

Tags: unison

Let's say that I want to sync a folder with unison, but I want to sync only .jpg files.

How I could do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the following lines to your profile:

```
ignore = Name ?*
ignorenot = Name *.jpg
```

Comment: ignore = Name ?* did not work with me, replaced with ignore = Name {,.}*{.*}

Answer (score 0):

Eight years later ... the accepted doesn't properly ignore files with no period, or dotfiles.

And any pattern (say, `Regex ^((?!.jpg).)*$`) that does matche these will also gobble directories that might have .jpg as a child. (See "Unison starts detecting updates..." under [Ignoring Paths](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#ignore) in the manual.)

The only way I've found is to let the sync proceed with those extra files included, and then use

```
find "$DEST" --type f ! -iname "*.jpg" -delete
find "$DEST" --type d -empty -delete
```

to kill them, and then clean up the empty directories. (In my case, I actually did

```
find "$DEST" --type d -empty ! -name ".stfolder" -delete
```

to preserve a SyncThing marker directory--don't ask.)

A potentially bad consequence of this is copying lots of extra data for a short time--in my case, some 3.5GB moves from one partition to another, and then is promptly deleted.